# How to connect strapi, graphql and postgres all together?

Tags: typescript, postgresql, graphql, strapi

Im new to strapi and i wanted to use graphql and postgreSQL with it and i looked at there documentation and it seems like you connect postgreSQL and strapi together but not postgres and graphql together. I just want graphql to connect to postgres with strapi thats really it.

Answer (score 1):

First, connect Strapi to PostgreSQL: https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/configurations.html#database

Then, add GraphQL according to the official docs:
https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/development/plugins/graphql.html#usage